# Cross joining unnested empty arrays

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table that is derived from a JSON schema like this:

```
{name: 'Foo', implies: []}
{name: 'Bar', implies: ['Foo']}
{name: 'Baz', implies: ['Foo', 'Bar']}
```

I'd like to unnest the `implies` field so that I have one `name` per value. For example:

```
name, implies
Foo,
Bar, Foo
Baz, Foo
Baz, Bar
```

The query I have is:

```
SELECT name, implies FROM table, UNNEST(implies) AS implies
```

But names with empty implies are dropped, so I don't get the field of name "Foo".

I'm unable to do a `FULL JOIN` on `UNNEST(implies)`:

```
 Array scan is not allowed with FULL JOIN: UNNEST expression
```

How can I get the expected output given this schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LEFT JOIN here

```
#standardSQL
SELECT name, implies 
FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(implies) AS implies
```

you can check this with dummy data from your question as

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
SELECT 'Foo' name, [] implies UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bar', ['Foo'] UNION ALL
SELECT 'Baz', ['Foo', 'Bar']
)
SELECT name, implies 
FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(implies) AS implies
```

with result as

```
Row name    implies  
1   Foo     null     
2   Bar     Foo  
3   Baz     Foo  
4   Baz     Bar
```